# Import mathjs as a JavaScript module fails

Tags: javascript, module, mathjs

I try to import [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html) as a module in a browser (client side). I copied [this file](https://unpkg.com/mathjs@6.6.4/dist/math.js) on the server, and then try to import the JS module, but it always fails. Here are some trial I already made:

```
import { mathjs } from "./math.min.js"
```

> SyntaxError: The requested module './../modules/math.min.js' does not
>   provide an export named 'mathjs'

```
import { math } from "./math.min.js"
```

> SyntaxError: The requested module './../modules/math.min.js' does not
>   provide an export named 'math'

```
import { create, all } from "./math.min.js"
```

SyntaxError: The requested module './math.min.js' does not provide an export named 'all'

I also try:

```
import("/math.min.js");
```

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'math' of undefined

Note that the path is OK, I checked. I'm probably missing something, but I can't find what I am doing wrong. Any help is welcome.

Here is a repl.it with the code: https://repl.it/@FifiLulu/NewJollyRoutes

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add:

```
<script type="module">
```

to your html file.

Comment: That's not the issue. The file index.js is imported with `import("/index.js")`. It works with other modules.